# Proof of funds for UK visitor visa

Tags: uk, international-travel, visa-refusals

I want to apply for the UK visitor visa for an exam and my father will be sponsoring me. Firstly, is it okay to show 3 month bank statement with monthly salary statements instead of 6 months bank statement? And also there is a big deposit in my father’s account but that is from his provident fund. If I show his provident fund statement and bank statement that shows the transfer, will it be enough proof?

Comment: Why can’t you provide 6 months’ worth of statements?

Comment: Well there are some inconsistencies before 3 months. Do you suggest I wait out another 3 months and then apply providing 6 months statement?

Comment: Probably, yes, if the nature of the inconsistencies is significant compared to the normal transactions through the account and the reasons cannot be explained easily.